# Finding and plotting intersection of functions

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
plotImageZoom = Plot[{20*x, (20/(4 - x)*#) & /@ {0.5, 1.5, 2.5}}, {x, 0, 1.5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 30}}, Ticks -> None, 
  LabelStyle -> {Thick, Bold, Thick, Bold}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

Which creates this:

[image]

**How can one make such an image ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Solve` to find the points of intersection and use the result to add the desired points and lines as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)to `Plot`:

```
points = x /. Solve[{(20/(4 - x)*#) == 20 x, 0 <= x <= 3/2}, x][[1]] & /@ 
      Rationalize[{0.5, 1.5, 2.5}];

Plot[{20*x, ## & @@ ( (20/(4 - x)*#) & /@ {0.5, 1.5, 2.5})}, {x, 0, 1.5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 30}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#, Style[Subscript["x", #2[[1]]], 16]} &,  points], None}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{#, 20 #} & /@ points], 
      Dashed, Thin, Line /@ ({{#, 0}, {#, 20 #}} & /@ points)}]
```

[image]

**Update:** To make *white background behind the dotted line* use

```
Epilog -> {CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[10], White, 
 Line /@ ({{#, 0}, {#, 20 #}} & /@ points) , 
 Black, AbsolutePointSize[12], Point[{#, 20 #} & /@ points],  
 Dashed, Thin, Line /@ ({{#, 0}, {#, 20 #}} & /@ points) }
```

[image]

Comment: Great !! Thank you so much !! :D

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but do you know how to make the white background behind the dotted line at the region where the dotted line intersects red lines ?

Comment: @james, thank you for the accept. I will update with a method to add thick white lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to find where the functions intersect is using `RegionIntersection` (introduced in version 10.0).

```
pts = RegionIntersection[
  {x, 20 x} /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1.5}} // Line,
  Table[{x, 20/(4 - x)*#}, {x, 0, 1.5, .1}] & /@ {0.5, 1.5, 2.5} // Line
  ]
Plot[
 Evaluate@Prepend[(20/(4 - x)*#) & /@ {0.5, 1.5, 2.5}, 20*x],
 {x, 0, 1.5},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {0, 30}},
 Ticks -> {
   MapThread[{#1, "x" <> ToString@#2} &, {pts[[1, ;; , 1]], Range[3]}],
   None
   },
 TicksStyle -> {{Black, Bold, 14}, None},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Red, Red},
 Epilog -> {
   {PointSize[.03], pts},
   {Thickness[.03], White, {{#1, 0}, {#1, #2 - 2}} & @@@ pts[[1]] // Line},
   {Thickness[.005], Dashed, {{#1, 0}, {##}} & @@@ pts[[1]] // Line}
   }
 ]
```

> Point[{{0.12919, 2.5838}, {0.418919, 8.37838}, {0.775434, 15.5087}}]

[image]

Also credit to @kglr's answer for the idea to use `Ticks` for the x's.